# click the button and increase number through component - angular

Tags: angular, button, service, components, increment

Hej,
I'm having having a problem with button which should increase number +=1 and display in the view this number.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterService } from '../common/services/counter.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {}
get count() {
    return this.counterService
  }
  set count(count){
    this.counterService.count += 1;
  }
}
```

counter.service

```
export class CounterService {
count = 0;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p> {{ counterService.count }}</p>
    <button  (click)="count()" class="btn btn-default form-control increaseBtn">INCREASE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can display 0 but when I'm stacked with incrementation. Thx in advance!

Comment: You are using the setter in a wrong way. Please read the accessors section here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
public getCount() {
  return this.counterService.count
}
public incCount(){
  this.counterService.count += 1;
}
```

in html:

```
<button  (click)="incCount()" class="btn btn-default form-control increaseBtn">INCREASE</button>
```

and in counter.service:

```
export class CounterService {
  public count = 0;
}
```

But better manage variables in service

Answer (score 3):

app.component.ts

```
<button type="text" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onShowLog()">Click Me</button>

<p *ngIf="showLog">{{ log }}</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})

export class AppComponent {
    log = 0;
    showLog = false;

    onShowLog(){
         this.showLog = true;
         return this.log = this.log + 1;
    }

}
```